# Azure cognitive search alternative

Tags: cloud, azure-cognitive-search

I am looking for an azure cognitive search alternative on an other cloud service.
Basically I like the idea to upload, search, upgrade and delete objects in cognitive search via a REST API with less programming effort.
The alternative should be able to store up to 50.000 objects which cause ~200mb memory load and provides a good search engine. Or do you folks know a way to search text in a postgres DB, which provides suggestions and spelling correction?

The actual problem is that azure cognitive search becomes very expensive as soon one needs the first plan (~80$ a month).

Comment: When you tried Cognitive Search, did you find that it required too much programming as you not only needed to ingest the data, but you needed to develop an application against it?  If this is the case, perhaps some of the solutions that our partners have created on top of Cognitive Search might be a good option?  

You mention an issue around memory load.  This makes me think that perhaps you want more of a client side / unmanaged search engine (such as technologies like Lucene, Elasticsearch or SOLR).

Comment: Hi @liam-cavanagh-msft, no its not an programming issue. In fact I love it. The problem ist that its very expensive (~80$) when one exceeds 50mb space. The first paid plan provides too much space and indizies I dont need.
So I am looking for an alternative which is cheaper or a service which can search in a postgres db for example

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  I don't think I have any good suggestions for a managed search service , but there is always the option of hosting something like Lucene or ElasticSearch in a VM or container that is fronted by a web service.  This of course comes with all the challenges of managing and securing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can basically build similar service using a combination of OCR , NLP and Search (Elastic search) so on AWS I would try Textract , Sagemaker , Amazon Comprehend , Elasticsearch you can find an example here

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/building-an-nlp-powered-search-index-with-amazon-textract-and-amazon-comprehend/

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/building-a-visual-search-application-with-amazon-sagemaker-and-amazon-es/

I used elasticsearch for autocomplete and auto suggestion and spell check, it is very powerful depending on the type of suggester you want :

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-suggesters.html

Comment: Thanks for your collection of services. I found a solution before you answered. I decided to use SearchBox, which is an Heroku add-on and based on ElasticSearch. With the cost of 9€/month and 1 GB space, it fits what I looked for.

Comment: I see but from what I see it does not have AI capability such as the ones provided by Azure Cognitive , it is just a layer on top of elasticsearch, Azure Cognitive provides much more capabilities, it would not be fair comparison